# isolate elements in _any but not all_ vectors with R

Tags: r

If you have a bunch of (character, numeric, whatever) vectors, what's a good way to extract the elements that are present in some/any but not all of those vectors?

I'm trying to figure out the column names that my tables *do not* have in common, and wondering what the smartest way to do this is?

I came up with this function (see my answer), but I'm wondering if there are sneakier ways to do this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# take an arbitrary number of vectors of the same type
ana <-
    function( ... ){        
        w <- unique( unlist( list( ... ) ) )
        v <- Reduce( intersect , list( ... ) )
        setdiff( w , v )
    }

x <- 1:3
y <- 2:4
z <- 3:5

# return everything but the `3` since that's in all of the vectors.
ana( x , y , z )
```

Comment: I think this is as as good as it can get, it has speed and readability. Tried an approach based on `table` and `length(...)`  out of curiosity. It was 2x slower.

Comment: thanks @Pafnucy!  the `unlist( list( ... ) )` makes me uneasy